# Are all those valuable programming guides and sample codes removed in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

In **Xcode 8** and before, the documentation window in **Xcode** provides various programming guides (like **TableView Programming Guide** and **Core Animation Programming Guide**) as well as sample codes, and I can bookmark them. But after I upgrade to **Xcode 9**, they all dissappeared. Are they really removed ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like Xcode has less of the non class reference documentation in it. There are at least a couple sample code projects for ARKit in there but they don't show up if you search for sample code.

It likely has to do with the change they made to the documentation structure online. They have a new simplified link for documentation now, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/. It doesn't appear to have everything in it and isn't as easy to navigate. The stuff that has been around for a while is still at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/navigation/.

I'd wager that Xcode now looks at the new documentation area for what it should show so it doesn't see everything anymore.

Comment: in short, every new xcode version apple releases is way much worse than the previous one... where are the Bookmarks too?.